# Change button colour from different form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm really new to c# and I'm doing this coursework which is about making a waiter app using visual studio.

The user presses on the seat number which is the button I want to change the colour of and opens a new form to place the order where the user chooses meals and submits the order. Upon submission I want the seat colour on the main form to change to yellow, which indicates that the order has been placed on that seat number.

Here's how the seat button looks in the main form

```
public void button_clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    button seatButton = (Button)sender;
    string seat = seatButton.text;
    placeOrder po = new placeOrder(seat);
    po.showDialog();
}
```

and here's how the submit order button looks in the submit order form

```
private void submitOrder_clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxMeals.Items.Count != 0)
       {
          alertbox.text = "You have placed your order successfully";

          // how to change seat button colour ?
       }
    else
       {
          alertbox.text = "Your meals list is empty";
       }
}
```

[image: here is a picture of the forms]

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: I can't find a way to do that

Comment: You need to pass the button as a parameter to the other form.  Or use the result of `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: `if (DialogResult.OK == po.ShowDialog()) { seatButton.BackColor = Color.Red; }`

Comment: Thanks Johnny but i need to change the seat button colour after the order is submitted on the 2nd form

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

1. Change the visibility of the button to `Public` in `frmMain`.
2. In the `submitOrder_clicked()` event of `frmChild1` do:

   ```
   (this.MdiParent as frmMain).btnChild.BackColor="RequiredColor";
   ```

Comment: what does `btnChild ` stands for ? is it the `button_clicked func` ?

Comment: btnChild is the name of the button you want to change color.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going to use this for more than one button, you can create a static reference to the button you just clicked.

```
public static Button CurrentButton;
public void button_clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    button seatButton = (Button)sender;
    string seat = seatButton.text;
    placeOrder po = new placeOrder(seat);
    CurrentButton = button;
    po.showDialog();
}
```

Then simply add the following line wherever you want to change the button's color:

```
    MainForm.CurrentButton.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```